# When calling enhancedLocation.getAsync() after adding a location in the webinterface, an empty list is returned

Tags: office-js

Since 22th of April 2019 EnhancedLocation has been added to to the Officejs preview. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.enhancedlocation?view=office-js)

When I get the EnhancedLocation in an interval:

```
setInterval(() => {
        Office.context.mailbox.item.enhancedLocation.getAsync((asyncResult) => {
            asyncResult.value.forEach(function (place) {
                console.log("Display name: " + place.displayName);
                console.log("Type: " + place.locationIdentifier.type);
                if (place.locationIdentifier.type === 
                    Office.MailboxEnums.LocationType.Room) {
                    console.log("Email address: " + place.emailAddress);
                }
            });
        });
    }, 5000);
```

After settting a location(jhon@doe.nl):
[setting location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B4Ra.png)

An empty list will be returned:

```
OSF.DDA.AsyncResult
status: "succeeded"
value: []
__proto__: Object
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: We tried using the same code given. It is working as expected and returning Locations in result. Are you using Enterprise or Consumer Outlook on Web?

Comment: We use a Office 365 for business on Web, so i think its Enterprise. Which version are you running?

Comment: is saveAsync called before enhancedLocation.getAsync() call ?

Comment: We're experiencing the same issue. After successfully calling addAsync to update the location field, we call getAsync but the returned list is empty. We didn't call saveAsync before getAsync and we don't expect that we must do it to get the data

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I figured that when saveAsync is not called. enhancedLocation.getAsync() will work. However I need to be able to retreive the enhanced location when saveAsync is called. Do you know how to resolve this? (a way to retreive PidLidGlobalObjectId without calling saveAsync would also work for me?)